# Как найти одинаковые строки в массиве и удалить их?

Tags: массивы, c++

В общем суть вопроса следующая. Программа создает файл примерно с таким содержанием:
1)1,2,3,4
2)5,2,3,4
3)1,2,8,4
4)1,2,3,3
5)4,3,2,1
n).......

Мне нужно удалить повторяющиеся(содержащие такие же элементы, но допустим в другом порядке) строки например 1 и 5. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант (концепция): считывать каждую строку в класс *T*, для которого определены operator==(const T&) и operator <(const T&). Объекты этого класса складывать в набор std::set< T > *M*. Тогда, если оператор сравнения будет распознавать элементы строк 1 и 5 (см. пример автора вопроса) как одинаковые, то новый элемент в набор *M* добавляться не будет. После прочтения всего исходного файла, в наборе останутся только уникальные экземпляры класса *Т*, так что можно будет просто всех их вывести в исходный файл, перезаписав его.

Comment: теоретически звучит не плохо, попробую реализовать

Comment: Только, если смотреть на приведённые данные, надо использовать не `std::set`, а `std::multiset`

Comment: alexlz, так ведь std::multiset даст возможность добавлять одинаковые объекты, что не нужно.

Comment: Это о чём. Т.е. я был не прав, написав, что multiset надо вместо set. Если не заботиться об эффективности, то глобальная структура будет `set<multiset<int> >`. И выводить из этого множества не надо, если старый порядок строк и элементов в строках имеет значение.

Comment: Теперь я понял ваше предложение. По-сути, вы предлагаете не писать свой класс *T* для хранения и сравнения элементов одной строки, а использовать std::multiset<int> вместо него.

Comment: в общем если это кому то пригодится то вот так это делается:
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#define N 5
int main()
{
int j,k,l,s;
int d[N]={0,0,0,0,0};
int x[N][4]={
1,2,3,4,
5,2,3,4,
4,3,2,1,
1,2,3,3,
4,3,2,1
}; 
for(j=0;j-N;j++)
 for(k=j+1;k-N;k++)
  if(!d[k])
   {
   for(s=l=0;l-4;l++) s^=x[j][l]^x[k][l];
   d[k]=!s;
   } 
for(j=0;j-N;j++,cout << endl)
 if(!d[j])
  for(k=0;k-4;k++) cout<<x[j][k]<<" ";
//return 0;
_getch();
}

Comment: ну если наставить enter`ов, после ";", то станет понятно о чем я, комментарии тут "лучшие".

Comment: Это решение явно в стиле  Си. Кроме неудобочитаемости (даже с переносом строк) из минусов хочу отметить нерасширяемость: например, увеличение числа элементов в одной строке до 9, или даже просто увеличении числа строк с 5 до произвольного количества приведет к неработоспособности. Все же с использованием STL и C++ можно решить задачу куда проще и элегантнее.

Answer (score 1):

[[@vladimir_ki](/users/4137/vladimir_ki)](/users/4137/vladimir_ki) а так?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string      line;
    set<multiset<int> > s;
    while(getline(cin,line)) {
        stringstream    lineStream(line);
        string      cell;
        multiset<int>   ms;

        while(getline(lineStream,cell,',')) {
            int cellint;
            stringstream    cellstream(cell);
            cellstream >> cellint;
            ms.insert(cellint); 
        }

        if(s.find(ms) == s.end()) {
            cout << line << endl;
            s.insert(ms);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**UPD** подчищен хвост result.

Comment: Да, это - хорошее решение, - все на C++ и STL. В первую очередь своей наглядностью того, что происходит. Возник вопрос: зачем нужна переменная result?

Comment: жаль "лайк" поставить не могу, спасибо за вариант, подогнал под себя. кстати, вот то ради чего я мучался: Дано натуральное число n. Выяснить, можно ли представить его в виде суммы 4 простых чисел. Вывести на печать все возможные варианты без повторений. С последней частью "варианты без повторений" и возникли проблемы. сама задача тут http://codepaste.ru/8957/ . еще раз спасибо

Comment: @vladimir_ki result? -- это важная штука. Самому лениво было думать над вводом csv, взял образец с stackoverflow. А это хвост, который забыл подчистить.

Comment: @alexlz понятно. Ну тогда можете его удалить из вашего примера, чтобы дальше он не размножался по просторам рунета :)

Comment: @saymonic_ А если следующие пробы делать из чисел не меньше испытанных, то как появятся повторения?

Comment: А я наверное что-то не понял. 

IMHO приведенная программа будет считать 1,2,3,4 и 4,3,2,1 (это мультимножества **ms**, входящие в множество **s**) **разными**, а по смыслу задачи, рассказанной автором в комментарии к этому ответу это **неверно**.

Т.е. программа решает не ту задачу.

---

Исправит положение сортировка элементов (cellint), перед их включением в ms.

Comment: Избавит от сомнений чтение описания STL. Внутрях множеств и мультимножеств элементы отсортированы. Так что сортировка перед включением может повлиять разве что на скорость.